# Help - transfering bitcoin old bitcoin core 0.12.0 wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have a old bitcoin core wallet 0.12.0 ... I tried to transfer bitcoin from this to a new Coinbase wallet 2 days ago... Nothing has shown up in Coinbase wallet and the status of the transation in bitcoincore shows sent - but with a ! and status 0/unconfirmed.... is this transaction ever going to work or is there a way to cancel? I dont seem to be able to do anything with it now... so am concerned about how I can I get bitcoin from this old wallet?

It also has years worth of syncing to do to catch up

Comment: You must wait untill the blockchain to catch up for your old wallet to send the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Export your private key(s) from 0.12.0 and import into a more recent version of the wallet, send from the newer version.

Comment: That won't solve anything, as he'd still need to synchronize the new wallet.

Comment: there are types of wallets other than full nodes that allow importing private keys. syncing a new full node is an option, but not the only option.

Comment: Of course, but "a more recent version of the wallet" in this case refers to Bitcoin Core, no? You could alternatively suggest importing into different wallet software, but that's a lot more complicated

Comment: it's definitely not more complicated. check this out. https://bitcoinelectrum.com/importing-your-private-keys-into-electrum/

Comment: That's still a lot more steps than just upgrading your Bitcoin Core version! Anyway, it seems strange that I'm arguing about what your answer means. I clearly misinterpreted it; you didn't mean upgrading Bitcoin Core, but transitioning to software with a different model entirely.